# Given a class in Visual Studio, how to find out which dll contains it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, .net-assembly

Working on modifying an existing .NET project. Given a C# class in Visual Studio, how can I find out which DLL has it?

The problem is that I want to use a method in this class in a new project so I need to find the correct DLL to add as a reference for the new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the assembly in the project properties. The output name of the DLL (which is what a Class Library project produces) is specified in there.

Answer (score 7):

Search for your class name in the object browser (Menu View -> Object Browser).
The assembly information window will contain the dll complete path.

Answer (score 3):

This can be rather frustrating and irritating - I found myself in a situation where I needed an answer to the OP's question and none of the above answers worked for me.

I had a program that imported some Roslyn DLLs. Later, after I'd become unsure as to which DLLs were really necessary, I was trying to find out which classes were in which DLLs.

For example, my program referenced class `MSBuildWorkspace`. Navigating to the class declaration I can see the namespace name, and the fully qualified name of the class is `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace`.

Opening the Object Browser, as suggested by @Spell, and searching for `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace` results in "Search found no results", which I'm guessing must be due to a bug in Visual Studio.

Fortunately, searching for just `MSBuildWorkspace` does find the class, but it still didn't tell me which DLL contains the class.

So what I needed to do was to click on the class name, which is shown as a link, in the smallish panel in the lower right part of Object Browser. This results in the left panel switching to a view of the DLLs and the classes they contain. Now I could see that class `MSBuildWorkspace` was in DLL `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces`, and right-clicking on that and selecting Copy and pasting the result into a text editor provided the full path to the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

There are some tools like [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) that will suggest adding `using` statements and even add a reference to the project. It seems you don't have something like that.

### Adding a reference for a Microsoft class

In that case (before I had tools), I google for

```
class <ClassName> site:msdn.microsoft.com
```

e.g.

```
class Process site:msdn.microsoft.com
```

which brings me to the [Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.90%29). On the MSDN page, it lists the namespace and assembly:

```
Namespace:  System.Diagnostics
Assembly:  System (in System.dll)
```

### Adding a reference of your own class in a different project

- Open the class definition (source code)
- Open the Solution Explorer
- Click the "Sync with active document" button
- [image: Sync with active document]
- Move up to the project
- Open properties (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Look at Application/Assembly Name